# opening google map in a tab on iphone not working

Tags: ios, iphone, google-maps

I am working with a Google Maps Tutorial (http://www.raywenderlich.com/81103/introduction-google-maps-ios-sdk-swift) and enhanced it by embedding it into a Tab Controller.  As soon as I have made it the second tab, it no longer works.

If I move it to the primary tab (default tab), it works fine but otherwise it doesn't appear to pull location or even show all controls.  I have moved the logic from viewDidLoad() to viewWillAppear() but that doesn't help either.

Any ideas on what could be causing this issue?

This is the code from the MapViewController.swift

```
//
//  MapViewController.swift
//  Feed Me
//
//  Created by Ron Kliffer on 8/30/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Ron Kliffer. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class MapViewController: UIViewController, TypesTableViewControllerDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate, GMSMapViewDelegate {

  @IBOutlet weak var addressLabel: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet weak var mapView: GMSMapView!
  @IBOutlet weak var mapCenterPinImage: UIImageView!
  @IBOutlet weak var pinImageVerticalConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
  var searchedTypes = ["bakery", "bar", "cafe", "grocery_or_supermarket", "restaurant"]

  let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
  let dataProvider = GoogleDataProvider()

  var randomLineColor: UIColor {
    get {
      let randomRed = CGFloat(drand48())
      let randomGreen = CGFloat(drand48())
      let randomBlue = CGFloat(drand48())
      return UIColor(red: randomRed, green: randomGreen, blue: randomBlue, alpha: 1.0)
    }
  }

  var mapRadius: Double {
    get {
      let region = mapView.projection.visibleRegion()
      let verticalDistance = GMSGeometryDistance(region.farLeft, region.nearLeft)
      let horizontalDistance = GMSGeometryDistance(region.farLeft, region.farRight)
      return max(horizontalDistance, verticalDistance)*0.5
    }
  }

  func fetchNearbyPlaces(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
    // 1
    mapView.clear()
    // 2
    dataProvider.fetchPlacesNearCoordinate(coordinate, radius:mapRadius, types: searchedTypes) { places in
      for place: GooglePlace in places {
        // 3
        let marker = PlaceMarker(place: place)
        // 4
        marker.map = self.mapView
      }
    }
  }

  @IBAction func refreshPlaces(sender: AnyObject) {
    fetchNearbyPlaces(mapView.camera.target)
  }

  @IBAction func mapTypeSegmentPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    let segmentedControl = sender as UISegmentedControl
    switch segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex {
    case 0:
      mapView.mapType = kGMSTypeNormal
    case 1:
      mapView.mapType = kGMSTypeSatellite
    case 2:
      mapView.mapType = kGMSTypeHybrid
    default:
      mapView.mapType = mapView.mapType
    }
  }

  func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView!, markerInfoContents marker: GMSMarker!) -> UIView! {
    // 1
    let placeMarker = marker as PlaceMarker

    // 2
    if let infoView = UIView.viewFromNibName("MarkerInfoView") as? MarkerInfoView {
      // 3
      infoView.nameLabel.text = placeMarker.place.name

      // 4
      if let photo = placeMarker.place.photo {
        infoView.placePhoto.image = photo
      } else {
        infoView.placePhoto.image = UIImage(named: "generic")
      }

      return infoView
    } else {
      return nil
    }
  }

  // 1
  func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
    // 2
    if status == .AuthorizedWhenInUse {

      // 3
      locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

      //4
      mapView.myLocationEnabled = true
      mapView.settings.myLocationButton = true
    }
  }

  func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView!, didTapMarker marker: GMSMarker!) -> Bool {
    mapCenterPinImage.fadeOut(0.25)
    return false
  }

  // 5
  func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {
    if let location = locations.first as? CLLocation {
      // 6
      mapView.camera = GMSCameraPosition(target: location.coordinate, zoom: 15, bearing: 0, viewingAngle: 0)

      // 7
      locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
      fetchNearbyPlaces(location.coordinate)
    }
  }

  func reverseGeocodeCoordinate(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
    let geocoder = GMSGeocoder()
    geocoder.reverseGeocodeCoordinate(coordinate) { response , error in

      //Add this line
      self.addressLabel.unlock()
      if let address = response?.firstResult() {
        let lines = address.lines as [String]
        self.addressLabel.text = join("\n", lines)

        let labelHeight = self.addressLabel.intrinsicContentSize().height
        self.mapView.padding = UIEdgeInsets(top: self.topLayoutGuide.length, left: 0, bottom: labelHeight, right: 0)
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.25) {
          self.pinImageVerticalConstraint.constant = ((labelHeight - self.topLayoutGuide.length) * 0.5)
          self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
      }
    }
  }

  func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView!, didTapInfoWindowOfMarker marker: GMSMarker!) {
    // 1
    let googleMarker = mapView.selectedMarker as PlaceMarker

    // 2
    dataProvider.fetchDirectionsFrom(mapView.myLocation.coordinate, to: googleMarker.place.coordinate) {optionalRoute in
      if let encodedRoute = optionalRoute {
        // 3
        let path = GMSPath(fromEncodedPath: encodedRoute)
        let line = GMSPolyline(path: path)

        // 4
        line.strokeWidth = 4.0
        line.tappable = true
        line.map = self.mapView
        line.strokeColor = self.randomLineColor

        // 5
        mapView.selectedMarker = nil
      }
    }
  }

  func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView!, willMove gesture: Bool) {
    addressLabel.lock()
    if (gesture) {
      mapCenterPinImage.fadeIn(0.25)
      mapView.selectedMarker = nil
    }
  }

  func didTapMyLocationButtonForMapView(mapView: GMSMapView!) -> Bool {
    mapCenterPinImage.fadeIn(0.25)
    mapView.selectedMarker = nil
    return false
  }

  func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView!, idleAtCameraPosition position: GMSCameraPosition!) {
    reverseGeocodeCoordinate(position.target)
  }

//  override func viewDidLoad() {
//    super.viewDidLoad()
//    locationManager.delegate = self
//    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
//    mapView.delegate = self
//  }

  override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        mapView.delegate = self
  }

  override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "Types Segue" {
      let navigationController = segue.destinationViewController as UINavigationController
      let controller = segue.destinationViewController.topViewController as TypesTableViewController
      controller.selectedTypes = searchedTypes
      controller.delegate = self
    }
  }

  // MARK: - Types Controller Delegate
  func typesController(controller: TypesTableViewController, didSelectTypes types: [String]) {
    searchedTypes = sorted(controller.selectedTypes)
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    fetchNearbyPlaces(mapView.camera.target)
  }

}
```

As you can see I have tried moving the code to activate the map from viewDidLoad() to viewWillAppear(), but I think the issue is with the delegate.  I think maybe the delegate is getting lost from the controller maybe over to the tabcontroller and hence the reason it can't draw it properly.

Comment: You need to post the code about your map view controller and tab controller.

Comment: You might try to call `locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()` in `viewDidAppear()`, also you might post some code about how you switch controllers in your tab view controller.

Comment: I am not doing anything special in the switching between controllers.  Each view controller is registered with the tab bar controller as view controllers using the standard UITabBarController class.

The suggestion you made regarding viewDidAppear() does get the location to update and center on the screen, but the location beacon (i guess that's what you would call it) doesn't appear and neither does the compass (you click it to center the map on your location).

Comment: Not sure why you call `dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)` in your delegate method?

Comment: That was from the original example project.  I implemented the example, and it works fine but when embedding it into a tab controller is where I am experiencing issues.  I was able to get github installed and integrated, and am currently uploading the project.

Comment: Source code can be downloaded from here http://github.com/crobertson98/Feed-Me.

Comment: I ran your code, I can see the compass control appear on the mapView: http://i.imgur.com/XF1a5PM.png

Comment: Did you run it in a simulator or on a phone?  Also, was it the first or second tab?

Answer (score 0):

I'm closer in understanding what is going on after hours of debugging.  The compass control only shows up if the didChangeAuthorizationStatus fires for my instance of CLLocationManager.  For some reason, when it is the second tab bar item, it does not fire as often as if it were the first tab bar item.  When it is the first tab bar item, it fires every time the application is open.  So, I moved my code from inside didChangeAuthorizationStatus into it's own function.  I call it from both viewDidAppear() and didChangeAuthorizationStatus() so the compass works properly and my location appears as well.

Thanks for all the help on this issue.  The CLLocationManager not firing consistently is a different question, so I'll answer this one and move on.  Thanks again.